# What is happening within this error message and how can I solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am completely at a loss as to how to solve this error I am receiving. If anyone can explain what is the error, that would be awesome.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        20: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        10: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
         9: from D:/[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]/[Projects-React]/rails-react/open-flights/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-0.19.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-0.19.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg_ext (LoadError)
        22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        20: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
        18: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
        17: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        16: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        15: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        14: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
        13: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
        12: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
        11: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
        10: from D:/[Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]/[Projects-React]/rails-react/open-flights/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
         9: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
         8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
         7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
         6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
         5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
         4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
         3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-0.19.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-0.19.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-0.19.0-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.7/pg_ext (LoadError)
```

Comment: Do you have pg in your Gemfile?

Comment: Is your database service up and accessible?

Comment: Try `gem install pg`